# centering divs in a row don't fall nicely in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 4 divs in a `row` like so:

```css
div.row {
  text-align: center;
}

div.row>div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <p>ggeggweg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <p>ggeggweg fwwfffwfw fwfwff f wfwf wffw fwfw f ww fw fw wf fw fw fw fw wf f</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <p>ggeggweg fwfwfwf fw ff wf wfwfwf wf wf wf </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <p>ggeggweg</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I want on small screens to show 2 divs in a "row", but since they don't have the same content they don't look good on small screen (when there are 2 in line).

[image]

Basically `float:none` messes them up, but without that rule the divs don't center.

Comment: I don't know if it was a bug in Bootstrap 3 but in Bootstrap 4 scaling works as you would expect it as you can see in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/z8ez2c4p/).

Answer (score 0):

```
div.equalHeight {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.inner{
  margin:auto;
}
```

Slightly edited your HTML by adding `div class="inner"` inside columns, which will let you set custom widths.

```css
div.row>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.equalHeight {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner {
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class=" row equalHeight">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>ggeggweg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>THis is a very Big Box. It will take too much of your space. And will grow, keep growing and growing and growing.................</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>ggeggweg km knka kmasd ibiasd oijasd jbabsd kjkas </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>ggeggweg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding display: flex; and flex-wrap: wrap does nothing except they stick to the left as normal.

Comment: Are they of equal height? And check the snippet, if that what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried with both setting the height and without, same thing, and they stick to the left, they dont get centered with flex

Comment: i just checked your snippet in full screen, they stick to the left and the point is that they get centered so i dont really understand your answer?

Comment: Yes I got what you are saying @dzoniboj, I'm on it :)

Comment: again it doesnt work if you give them fixed width, they should behave as if they were in a fixed with margin 0 auto container.

Comment: Yea and it does not work, you need to follow my css and the col divs should have a fixed width, they shouldn't take up 100% of screen width, not with divs inside of them.

Comment: Well, you need to workaround, as what you are requesting is manipulating class `col-*-*` by assigning your css `div.row>div`. You are giving a fixed width to a container, which is supposed to be responsive.